# Automate the creation of secondary mailbox in Outlook 2016

Tags: active-directory, exchange, automation, exchange-2016, microsoft

I allow myself to do this post in order to have your help.
I am currently looking for a solution to automate the addition of a secondary mailbox in Outlook 2016.
I saw a lot of stuff including the "zeroconfigexchange" registry tool however I failed to implement it because it looks like I don't have the registry values (screenshot attached).
Can you help me please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x8tt.png)

Comment: please be more specific about the issue.

Comment: The problem is simple in itself, I would like to automate the addition of a secondary mailbox on outlook 2016.
Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the **[ZeroConfigExchange](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-global-customer-service/zeroconfigexchange-automating-the-creation-of-an-outlook-profile/ba-p/389691)**?

Based on my test and research, our clients don't have this registry key by default and we need create it in the following locations:

**`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover`**(**xx** represents the current Office version such as 16.0)

**`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover`**

Then change the default profile with a new name different with existing ones and create a new profile for this new name in registry key:

**Default Profile Setting**: *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Outlook*

**New Profile**: *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Outlook\Profiles*

More details about this process: **[ZeroConfigExchange](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-global-customer-service/zeroconfigexchange-automating-the-creation-of-an-outlook-profile/ba-p/389691#:%7E:text=For%20Outlook%202013/2016,Close%20Regedit.)**

Because you are using Outlook 2016, you could use the following .reg file to create these registry keys(Before running them, please backup the original keys and don't change other non-related ones.):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover]
"ZeroConfigExchange"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\AutoDiscover]
"ZeroConfigExchange"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook]
"DefaultProfile"="ZeroConfigExchange"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\ZeroConfigExchange]
```

If you want to apply the ZeroConfig on domain-joined clients, GPO is suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ivan_Wang !
I have executed your .reg file that you sent me.
However now it is the part profile which does not seem to be functional.
I did create the values ​​(see screenshot) but I do not have a test profile then which is implemented in the application.

Comment: Did you login to windows with a domain account?

Comment: No i'm login with a local account.

Comment: *ZCE is a registry setting that tells Outlook to create a new profile using the SMTP address from Active Directory and to then leverage Autodiscover.* (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-global-customer-service/zeroconfigexchange-automating-the-creation-of-an-outlook-profile/ba-p/389691#:~:text=ZCE%20is%20a%20registry%20setting%20that%20tells%20Outlook%20to%20create%20a%20new%20profile%20using%20the%20SMTP%20address%20from%20Active%20Directory%20and%20to%20then%20leverage%20Autodiscover.).

Comment: If it's a local account, ZCE doesn't seem to work except if it has AD attributes(Domain account). If you want to add a secondary mailbox via ZCE, you may need to login to windows with a domain account, create a profile via ZCE which will configure a mailbox in outlook with the current windows credential, and then add your mailbox to this profile and set as the primary(default) mailbox.